# Multiple Fact Tables-Kylin

Tags: olap, olap-cube, fact-table, kylin

1. I am aware that Apache Kylin only allows one Fact Table per OLAP cube.
2. Is there a way to analyse a database with multiple Fact Tables using OLAP?
3. Alternatively, Can we query from multiple cubes simultaneously in a single job on Apache Kylin?

Regards
Anish Dhiman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved. I created multiple cubes, each containing a single fact table in Apache Kylin. While querying, I accessed each cube in a sub-query. 
As a result of this, I was then able to query collectively from all cubes.

Comment: Did you join across multiple fact tables at run time? can you give example of your sub-query?

Comment: I am also able to run sub-query but can't able to run join query over it